# Inconsistencias con el LISTVIEW.BUILDER

Tags: flutter

el widget de respuesta conserva la posicion sin importar cuantos comentarios agregue, es decir no sigue a su "comentario padre" en la posicion del indice

los widgets se agreagan de arriba hacia abajo.
[agrego caja de comentario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dDD5.png) ---
[respondo al comentario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpGw0.png) ---
[si agrego otro comentario, la respuesta va a pasar al comentario recien agregado, no se queda donde respondi inicialmente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkAho.png)

para que esto no ocurra no puedo responder al primer comentario por , solo puedo empezar a responder desde el segundo comentario y de esto se desprende OTRO PROBLEMA...
cuando tengo varios comentarios con sus respuestas el widget que me muestra la respuesta va desapareciendo a medida que hago scroll en la pantalla.

llevo dias con esto ya no se me ocurre que hacer... dejo mi codigo, muchas gracias!

por cierto soy nuevo en flutter

codigo que contiene la caja de comentarios

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:artisans_portafolio/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../model/Model.dart';

class Pruebas extends StatefulWidget {
  const Pruebas({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Pruebas> createState() => _PruebasState();
}

class _PruebasState extends State<Pruebas> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _commentController = TextEditingController();
  bool _estaEscribiendo = false;

  **final List<CommentaryBox> _cajaComentarios = [];**

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of<Model>(context);
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      expand: false,
      maxChildSize: 0.8,
      initialChildSize: 0.6,
      minChildSize: 0.6,
      builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController controller) => Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: **ListView.builder(
              controller: controller,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => _cajaComentarios[i],
              itemCount: _cajaComentarios.length,
              //
              reverse: false,**
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(height: 10),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Visibility(
              visible: model.mostrarInputComentarios,
              child: _inputComment(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /*

  */

  Widget _inputComment() {
    final model = Provider.of<Model>(context);
    return SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                controller: _commentController,
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmit,
                onChanged: (comentario) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (comentario.isNotEmpty) {
                      _estaEscribiendo = true;
                    } else {
                      _estaEscribiendo = false;
                    }
                  });
                },
                decoration:
                    const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'comment'),
                focusNode: model.focusNode2,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
              child: Platform.isIOS
                  ? CupertinoButton(
                      child: const Text('comment'),
                      onPressed: _estaEscribiendo
                          ? () => //si el boton de respuesta esta en true, entonces cambiar a _handleResponse

                              //*65
                              _handleSubmit(_commentController.text.trim())
                          : null)
                  : Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                      child: IconTheme(
                        data: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
                        child: IconButton(
                            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                            onPressed: _estaEscribiendo
                                ? () => _handleSubmit(
                                    _commentController.text.trim()) //*65
                                : null),
                      ),
                    ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  _handleSubmit(String texto) {
    if (texto.isEmpty) return;

    _commentController.clear();

    **final comentarios = CommentaryBox(
      animationController: AnimationController(
          vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400)),
      text: texto,
    );
    _cajaComentarios.insert(0, comentarios);
    comentarios.animationController.forward();**

    setState(() {
      _estaEscribiendo = false;
    });
  }
}
```

este es el codigo de la caja de comentarios que contiene el listview. builder de la respuesta

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:animate_do/animate_do.dart';
import 'package:expandable_text/expandable_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../model/Model.dart';
import 'Response_Widget.dart';

class CommentaryBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final AnimationController animationController;
  // final void Function()? onPressResponse;
  final void Function()? eraseCommentary;

  const CommentaryBox({
    Key? key,
    // required this.size,
    required this.text,
    required this.animationController,
    // this.onPressResponse,
    this.eraseCommentary,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // final Size size;

  @override
  State<CommentaryBox> createState() => _CommentaryBoxState(
      // onPressResponse,
      eraseCommentary,
      animationController);
}

class _CommentaryBoxState extends State<CommentaryBox>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isAnswering = false;
  final _responseController = TextEditingController();

  // final void Function()? onPressResponse;
  final void Function()? eraseCommentary;
  final AnimationController animationController;
  bool _deployText = false;
  bool _inputResp = false;
  bool _showComments = false;
  **final List<ResponseWidget> responseBox = [];**

  _CommentaryBoxState(
    // this.onPressResponse,
    this.eraseCommentary,
    this.animationController,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final model = Provider.of<Model>(context);

    // final comunicacion = Provider.of<Model>(context);

    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor:
          CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.bounceIn),
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: animationController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Divider(),
            _Header(
              eraseCommentaryHeader: eraseCommentary,
            ),
            // _ExpandPanel(size: size),
            _ExpandableText(
              texto: widget.text,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              // height: size.height * 0.07,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  _TextButton(
                    elevation: 5,
                    primaryColor: Colors.white,
                    // onSurfaceColor: Colors.red,
                    backGroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    text: 'i like',
                    onpressed: () {},
                  ),
                  const VerticalDivider(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(211, 158, 158, 158),
                    thickness: 1,
                    indent: 10,
                    endIndent: 10,
                  ),
                  _TextButton(
                    elevation: 5,
                    primaryColor: Colors.white,
                    onSurfaceColor: Colors.red,
                    backGroundColor: Colors.teal,
                    text: 'comment',
                    onpressed: () {
                      model.mostrarInputComentarios = false;
                      _inputResp = true;
                      // });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Visibility(
              visible: _showComments,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  
               

                  // initiallyExpanded: true,
                  title: _deployText
                      ? Text('see less commentaries')
                      : Text('see commentaries'),
                  onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        _deployText = expanded;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  children: [
                    **ListView.builder(
                      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (_, i) => responseBox[i],
                      itemCount: responseBox.length,
                      reverse: true,**
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _inputResp,
              child: Container(
                child: _inputResponse(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _inputResponse() {
    final model = Provider.of<Model>(context);
    return SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _inputResp = false;
                  model.mostrarInputComentarios = true;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                // cursorColor: Colors.red,
                autofocus: true,
                controller: _responseController,
                onSubmitted: _handleResponse,
                onChanged: (comentario) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (comentario.isNotEmpty) {
                      _isAnswering = true;
                    } else {
                      _isAnswering = false;
                    }
                  });
                },
                decoration:
                    const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Responder'),
                focusNode: model.focusNode2,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
              child: Platform.isIOS
                  ? CupertinoButton(
                      child: const Text('Comentar'),
                      onPressed: _isAnswering
                          ? () => //si el boton de respuesta esta en true, entonces cambiar a _handleResponse

                              //*65
                              _handleResponse(_responseController.text.trim())
                          : null)
                  : Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                      child: IconTheme(
                        data: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
                        child: IconButton(
                          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_isAnswering) {
                              _handleResponse(_responseController.text.trim());
                            } else {
                              null;
                            }
                            setState(() {
                              _showComments = true;
                              model.mostrarInputComentarios = true;
                              _inputResp = false;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  _handleResponse(String respuesta) {
    final model = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false);

    if (respuesta.isEmpty) return;

    _responseController.clear();

    **final nuevaRespuesta = ResponseWidget(
      respuesta: respuesta,
      animationController: AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      ),
    );
    responseBox.insert(0, nuevaRespuesta);
    nuevaRespuesta.animationController.forward();**

    setState(() {
      model.mostrarComentarios = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Quizás sea cosa mía, puede ser, pero creo que tendrías que editar la pregunta porque se entiende medio regular. Recuerda que cuanto mejor redactada y clara esté la duda, más fácil será para los demás ayudarte. Y eso no quiere decir que la pregunta sea kilométrica.

Comment: @Manuel pregunta editada muchas gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

hay varios problemas en tu codigo, la identacion no permite darle una buena lectura,te sugiero identalo y vuelvelo a poner, otras 2 dos cosas que deberias considerar es.
1 - Si no puedes responder el primer comentario quita el "DraggableScrollableSheet"  y modifícalo por un Container, haz un debug con un print en varias arte de tu modelo, para ver que datos se están enviando, y si estos mismos, se están enviando de manera correcta.

2-. Este maquetado lo veo mal hecho, tal vex tambien eso causa, un comportamiento no esperado en tu App

```
 builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController controller) => Column(
```

lo que haría para llevar mas organización es crear un archivo aparte , y maquetaría solamente dicho widget => investiga el tema de  customs widgets , para que tomes el contexto, posterior maqueta siempre dentro de un Container, y toma como hijo de primera opción un Expanded para evitar desbordamientos, y por ultimo hijo la Columna.